# How do you make relational post types in Wordpress?

Tags: custom-post-types, database, metabox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linking Two Post Types](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16292/linking-two-post-types)

I have a post type, referred to as "Press Release" and another called "People".  I need to be able to connect the two together.  MY end goal is to have a drop down of "People" post types within the "Press Release" post type that allows you to select an author.

Is there a way to create relational post types and am I using that term correctly?

Comment: Yeah...use Scribu's Posts2Posts plugin.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. Do you really need a whole post type for People? You could do this as a custom taxonomy and assign it to the Press Release post type.

You could create a custom user role, and then utilize that to assign an "author" to each Press Release.

If you want to keep everything you have now as is, your best bet would be to create a [custom meta box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box), which populates a select field with all of the "People" listed in it. Then save it using [update_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta)

You could also utilize the post_parent field and assign the ID of the "People" post to it.

As you can see, there are several options. Perhaps others have more.