# Define a Permalink Structure by Post and Page

Tags: permalinks

All, I have a post that works fine with a permalink setup. However, I also have a page called gallery. What I would each post can have a page. So for example I have a post named business-name so my URL would look like this:

http://website.com/business-name

I then want to click on a gallery link for this and that is a page I have created in wordpress. So I was looking to have a URL structure like this:

http://website.com/business-name/gallery

If I change my permalink structure to something like this:
/%postname%/%page%/

Then I go to the second link in my question it overwrites the URL to this:
http://website.com/gallery

Is something like this possible with a post and then a page?

Thanks

Comment: I would look at using `add_rewrite_endpoint` like in [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/94365/4771).

Comment: @Milo I think this looks helpful. This answer specifies a certain template though. My code is actually in a Page within Wordpress and uses a default template that I assign in the dashboard. Is there a way to call the gallery page instead of a template?

Comment: @Milo I would then like to load the gallery page but since it started with a post I could declare the $post as global variable inside the page and use the $post->ID to only select certain images for the gallery because I have a custom $wpdb query on this page to filter by that ID. I hope this helps and gives a little more clarity. Thanks!

Comment: The code is in the actual page within the admin instead of on a template. I know I could create a template but it wasn't working correctly because it had a bunch of short codes that don't recognize the closing tag in do_shortcode and don't want to have to rewrite that code.

Answer (score 0):

Since posts are not hierarchical and pages are - even if you're linking to a page from a post, there's nothing telling WordPress that they're related. So the urls you're going to get will be www.site.com/page or www.site.com/post.

If you'd like to relate them, you can either use Pages for both and take advantage of the hierarchy Wordpress provides (see link below). Or you can have a [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types) and set the **hierarchy** parameter to true. You can also set your custom post type to behave like a page if that's the reason why you're trying to use post > page.

- [WordPress explains the "Post Types" available, e.g. post and
  page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types)
- [How to create a child page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#To_create_a_subpage)

You may have other options, but I'm not sure what the circumstances are for your site, and why you'd be using a post and a page as two separate entities and trying to relate them. Perhaps if you can explain why you're trying to build it as post > page, I can provide more options for you.

Also don't forget about categories, if you're using a post simply to have the url be www.site.com/something/gallery, you can also take advantage of categories.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I don't know if the hierarchy would work because a page would be associated with multiple posts. So I would have a lot of different posts and for each business I would like to have the same gallery page because I have code in there to select certain images based on post id. I wouldn't make the gallery page have a parent because each post would be a parent of that page. Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh I see, so then you'd have Business A and Business B, and Gallery Page might be a child of both posts? This plugin can help you relate custom post types, so instead of having post > page, you'd have custom post type > custom post type. http://wp-types.com/documentation/user-guides/creating-post-type-relationships/ I can see what I find on doing this manually if you don't want the plugin route.

Comment: Also try this older question about relating two custom post types: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16292/linking-two-post-types